# How to pass autho 2 details white creating a test suite in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a test suite in Azure DevOps by using the Rest API. But here I am not sure how to provide the security details.

They have mentioned below details in docs. I am passing it in Postman like this. I tried giving my credentials in client ID and Client Secret as well. Please guide

[image]

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).","typeName":"System.Web.HttpException, System.Web","typeKey":"HttpException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to call Azure DevOps REST API, in your question, it uses Oauth 2.0 flow to authenticate, you could follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) to get the token and call the API.

In your case, if it is not necessary to use Oauth 2.0 flow to do the authentication, actually I recommend you to use PAT(personal access token) to call the API, just generate one and use it in the postman, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).